# Does $x \to a$ imply $x^n\to a^n$?

Tags: integration, limits, functions, derivatives

Is it correct that if x tends to any number say 'a' then x^n tends to a^n (where n any number) ?
If yes, then what if x tends to 0 or 1 ?

Comment: Can $a$ also be complex?

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ is continuous, then $x^2$ is continuous, as is $x^3, \dots, x^n, n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then as $x \to a$, $f(x) = x^n \to a^n$ as the other answer points out.

(The product of two continuous functions is itself continuous).

Comment: You are right but if x tends to 1 then say if x=0.9 then the square or cube or any other tends it to 0 instead of 1. @modeset

Comment: @neeraj How can $x$ tend to 1 and be $0.9$ at the same time?

Comment: @neeraj : Are you conflating the limit $n \rightarrow \infty$ with the limit $x \rightarrow 1$?  These are not the same limits and this is a standard example where reversing the order of limits yields different results...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if $x \rightarrow a$, then $x^2 \rightarrow a^2$. This is precisely because the function $f(x)=x^2$ is *continuous* at (any) $a$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=x^n$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is continuous.

Hence

$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)=f(\lim_{x \rightarrow a}x)=f(a)$.